# Why do we get some explicit references in Shakespearean plays that are meant for something else?

Tags: william-shakespeare, romeo-and-juliet, julius-caesar

First of all, by “explicit contents” I really mean the *that* thing.

In Shakespeare's play *Julius Caesar* when Brutus had planned everything and the night before the assassination he was in his room he had a little [conversation](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/characters/charlines.php?CharID=Portia&WorkID=juliuscaesar&cues=1) with his wife Portia. During the conversation Portia says

> Giving myself a voluntary wound 
>   Here, in the thigh: can I bear that with patience.

Why we got such an explicit reference in between such a serious and intellectual scene? Why writers put those things in plays which shouldn’t contain it (in my opinion).

I got one more example (suggested by @Rand al’Thor) from Romeo and Juliet, Act II, Scene IV we find

> "the bawdy hand of the [clock] dial is now upon the prick of noon".

Please understand that I’m not criticising any playwright all I want is to know why it’s important to make such references when things are better without them (in my opinion).

**DEFENCE**: Users are asking me to clear out what I think about “thighs”, well (@MattThrower has pointed out) it is “thigh” which is used in that verse not the “thighs”. I think the word “thigh” refer to something explicit or as something *pre* to *reproduction* act because a women don’t talk about their body parts which are close to *genitals* (as far as I have been around with relatives or acquaintances) and “thigh” is quite close (near) to *it*. The problem is why would a woman inflict a wound on her “thigh” rather than on any other place, what’s the significance of “thigh” in that verse.

Comment: You say that these lines are  'explicit', ie *stated clearly and in detail, leaving no room for confusion or doubt* Therefore could you clarify what exactly you think it is that they state? Why do you think a woman inflicting a wound on herself to demonstrate her strength is 'explicit' and at odds with serious intellectual themes? What is it you imagine when you read 'twisting in the fingers'?

Comment: The more plausible explanation is that you are reading sexual meaning into passages that don't have any sexual meaning.

Comment: At least for Shakespeare, part of it is that, well, sex sells and they wanted to get butts into seats. And it's often seated in puns and other wordplay because that was considered to be the smart way to make a joke, so the sex joke as a pun sold well to both the lowbrow and highbrow patrons.

Comment: @Knight Every source I've looked at says 'fingers', if you think those are all typos you need to link to your source. Even if it is 'twisting in the lingers', what is a 'linger', what is *explicit* about terror twisting in them? The thigh is a part of the leg that almost ever human has, it is not particular to women and it is not, in and of itself, sexual. if you say these references are explicit, you should not need to resort to saying that they 'reflect something', it would be explained in the text.

Comment: @Spagirl As far as **thighs** are concerned, if I’m understanding it wrong, then please explain what you understood by it. According to me, voluntary wound in thighs refers to intercourse, I may be wrong. Please explain why wound in thighs only, not any where else?

Comment: @Knight Thank you for the edit, but as I said, I'm confident that site has a typo. Your question, as to why explicit references are included relies upon it being a fact that explicit referenced actually exist in the text you quote. But it is clear that you are actually talking about references you believe to be *implied*. You cannot or will not tell us **why** you are reading a wounded thigh as an explicit reference. To put it bluntly, a thigh is not a vulva.

Comment: @Spagirl Please [see this](https://daily.bhaskar.com/news/JM-MYTH-duryodhana-right-or-wrong-5530061-PHO.html) where it is written "*After losing the game of gamble, Duryodhan had asked Draupadi to sit on his left thigh*". You see here thighs does have a clear cut implication.

Comment: @Knight Context is important. I don't know about the Mahabharata, but certainly a Shakespeare play and a modern rock song might use the same word in two very different meanings.

Comment: Knight, this question is attracting close votes, I think for two reasons. Firstly, it's a bit **too broad** to ask about different playwrights in the same question: the answers for Shakespeare and for Eliot might be very different, as they lived in different times and cultures. Secondly, **your examples aren't very good ones**: I don't know about Eliot, but there are a *lot* of dirty (sexual) jokes in Shakespeare, things much more clearly so than just mentioning thighs. However, there may be a solution! [cont]

Comment: [cont] If you do a massive [edit] to make the question simply ***"Why does Shakespeare make sexual references in his plays?"*** it could be fine, and then maybe you can ask another question about Eliot. I don't want to make such a drastic change without your blessing, but I really suggest you do that: it would solve both the problems that are making people criticise and close-vote. For a clearer example, try *"the bawdy hand of the [clock] dial is now upon the prick of noon*", from [*Romeo & Juliet*, Act II Scene IV](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/romeo_juliet/romeo_juliet.2.4.html).

Comment: @Randal’Thor Thank you for informing me (my reputations are less than 300 So I cannot see the close votes). I’m making the edits as we your suggestion.

Comment: @Knight Reference to a "thigh" is not automatically sexual. Check it in a dictionary: it's simply a part of the anatomy. Its proximity to the sexual organs means it is sometimes used "explicitly" but that's rare and is normally plural (thighs) since the sex organs sit between them. Your example of "sit on his left thigh" sounds to me like it might be a precursor to sexual activity - sitting on someone's lap for a cuddle - than an actual explicit reference. Your example from Julius Caesar is certainly not sexual.

Comment: Good edit. I've now upvoted the question and removed my vote to close. Sexual references in Shakespeare is a well-known thing on which whole books have been written. (I'd still suggest you remove the "thigh" example too, since there's not much evidence that it's meant to be a sexual reference and, again, there are so many others in Shakespeare plays.) @SeanDuggan seems to have the beginnings of a reasonable answer in his comment.

Comment: @Randal’Thor I respect your suggestions but if I remove that *thigh* examples then the originality of my question would be lost.

Comment: @MattThrower Yes. It may be the case.

Comment: @Knight If you feel that thighs are essential to your question then I think it is important that you make a clearer case for references to them being ‘explicit’ and to what it is you think they are explicit about, as opposed to eg merely hinting at previous or future intimacy. As the question stands my close-vote remains, I’m afraid.

Comment: @Spagirl How about now? See the defence.

Comment: @Knight so you think that Shakespeare must have been talking about sex in Elizabethan England because the women you know now don’t mention thighs? I think that this ‘defence’ fails to take into account different cultures and the fact that the Portia quote comes from a privy conversation between a woman and her spouse.

Comment: Yes, you need to take different cultures into account here. I don't know where you're from, but most women I know (in Britain/Europe) wouldn't have any issues or embarrassment about mentioning thighs - even among friends, let alone to their husbands. Again, the general question about sexual references in Shakespeare is a good one, but the thigh example isn't.

Comment: @Randal’Thor All right, Can you please tell me what she meant by the wounds in thigh?

Comment: @Knight Literally a wound in the thigh, like [this](http://thescratched.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/scratch11.jpg) or [this](https://www.nydailynews.com/resizer/_EmLZCekqRfgDG3bx_Oi6wFeBbY=/800x1066/top/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-tronc.s3.amazonaws.com/public/47QFAYJ2R5NYQKHA6V2JE5GNZU.jpg)?

Comment: @Randal’Thor What she wanted to say by that? I mean why she compared that pain with keeping the secret?

Comment: @Knight You could ask a separate question about that specific quote, since it's quite separate from the question about sexual references in Shakespeare plays.

Answer (score 5):

The discussion of sexual allusions or inferences in Shakespeare has been going on for a century or more. There can be no discussion, though, about the second quotation. (the bawdy hand of the dial is now upon the prick of noon). It's dirty. To answer Knight's question: Shakespeare's trade was theater, not literature. He wrote with his audience in mind, not literary critics and scholars. The word "prick" appears six times in Act II, Scene 4 - and nowhere else in *Romeo and Juliet*. It is there to entertain his audience, who would have started chuckling at the fourth or fifth "prick." Maybe it's a stretch, but one might also say he was training his audience, training them to listen, training them for *Hamlet*, *Lear*, *The Tempest*.

Answer (score 2):

The most famous study of Shakespeare's "explicit references" is [*Shakespeare's Bawdy: A Literary & Psychological Essay and A Comprehensive Glossary*](https://www.routledge.com/Shakespeares-Bawdy/Partridge/p/book/9780415254007) by Eric Partridge (first published in 1947).
The book contains a 48-page introduction, followed by a 175-page glossary.

I hope it is clear that what is considered taboo or inappropriate varies through time and from culture to culture. On page 33, Partridge writes,

> On the other hand, there is much evidence to show that in late-Elizabethan, in Jacobean, and in Caroline times,
>   women spoke very freely of sex in the presence of men and that the men and women of those times conversed together,
>   with considerable freedom, on the theme of fornication and 'wedding and bedding'.
>   The comedies of Ben Jonson, the comedies and tragi-comedies of Beaumont & Fletcher, Heywood, Massinger, Middleton, offer many proofs of this freedom.
>   Shakespeare and Beaumont & Fletcher were quite as 'free' as were Dryden, Etherege, Wycherley, Congreve.

In the fifth and last part of the introduction, Partridge asks how Shakespeare compared with other Elizabethan and Jacobean dramatists in the matter of sex and bawdiness, and writes,

> Of all the dramatists flourishing in the Elizabethan and Jacobean periods, Shakespeare is the wittiest, profoundest, most idealistic yet most cynical,
>   and, proportionally to the *corpora operum*, the most abundant: Lyly, Marlowe, Kyd, Greene—Ben Jonson, Webster, Tourneur, Heywood, Dekker, Massinger,
>   Middleton, Beaumont & Fletcher: all these men are inferior, in all those respects, to Shakespeare, and only Jonson in his comedies
>   and Beaumont & Fletcher, whether in comedy or in tragi-comedy, are as smutty; but unfortunately the smut of Ben Jonson, as of the collaborators, is less witty, (...)

Partridge also claims that Shakespeare's interest in women and their sexual features "was part of his character and his temperament" (page 21) and that he did not want to hide this.
He does not believe that Shakespeare's bawdy jokes were concessions to the [groundlings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundling) (page 3).